# DevExpress RepositoryItemLookUpEdit: conditional styling of values in the dropdown list

Tags: devexpress

I've looked at the events for the LookUpEdit (when used as the row editor in a VerticalGrid, so a `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit`) and don't see how to style rows in the dropdown conditionally, based on some other column's value in the row which corresponds to the displayed value.

For example, if an item listed in the dropdown has a currentStatus of "out of stock", it might be grayed out with strikethrough. The out of stock item cannot simply be excluded from the dropdown; it has to be in the list to make sense of historical data.

Is conditional styling possible with this particular editor?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. Consider using GridLookUpEdit instead (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsGridLookUpEdittopic).